# Is there any reasonable way to crawl the code snippet from answers in Stackoverflow?

Tags: html, web-crawler

As the title tells, I want to known whether there is a promising way to detect code blocks in technical website like Stackoverflow. Detecting the pattern of DOM tree seems to be not a good one as the layout could be changed in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [stackexchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) may be what you are searching for.

Using [stack apps](https://stackapps.com/users/login?returnurl=/apps/oauth/register), you can gather some user-submitted data easily.

Stack Apps even has [it's own](https://stackapps.com/) community where you can ask specific questions.

You can extract answers to specific questions using the [/answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers) GET API.